# Django/Jinja2 : Generate (data for) CSV via template syntax

Tags: python, django, csv, jinja2

I'd like to generate the data for a CSV file (or any reasonable export format) using template-like syntax for accessing the fields of my django objects. For example, the spec for the output fields could be:

```
employee.id
employee.manager.first_name
employee.user.last_login
employee.contact.phone_number
```

Where the fields are specified using the same syntax as I'd use in a Django or Jinja2 template.

I'd also love to be able to use filters just as I do in a django/jinja template:

```
employee.user.last_login|date:"c"
```

Given this spec and a list of objects, I'd like to produce rows of data from my objects. I can then generate CSV, XML, etc, from this data.

I started to write something that does this, but it quickly gets complex, and I'm thinking I can probably use some existing piece of the Django/Jinja2 templating engine.

Is there something that allows me to access my objects via Django/Jinja2 syntax?

Comment: Your question is super unclear. "something that allows me to access my objects via Django syntax"? ummmm, other than saying "employee.id"? What?

Comment: Or do you not know what a queryset is?

Comment: I know what a queryset is, and I have a queryset at hand. I'm not sure how to clarify - I'd like to specify the fields I'm interested in via the django/jinja syntax and use that to generate data from my queryset.

Comment: just... loop over each result in the queryset and do EXACTLY what you're doing. I'm sorry, but I'm really very confused about which part *you* are confused about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, generating CSV data with any technique other than the `csv` module will not win you many friends; it's the right tool for the job.

the most *convenient* way to generate output with that module is with [`writer.writerows()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.csvwriter.writerows), which takes a nested list (or rather, iterator of sequences).  Generators are a good way of expressing exactly that:

```
def csv_spec(queryset):
    for employee in queryset:
        yield (
            employee.id,
            employee.manager.first_name,
            employee.user.last_login,
            employee.contact.phone_number)

w = csv.writer(outfile)
w.writerows(csv_spec(something))
```

---

Edit: So you are saying you want something like a template for the same reason we use templates, but which produces CSV instead of text.  You can ask jinja to parse and process the sorts of expressions it has in
placeholders without a full template.

Assuming we have some data:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> Employee = namedtuple('Employee', 'id manager user contact')
>>> Person = namedtuple('Person', 'first_name last_name')
>>> Account = namedtuple('Account', 'username password last_login')
>>> Contact = namedtuple('Contact', 'phone_number email')
>>> data = [
...     Employee(0, Person('Alice', 'Brown'),
...              Account('abrown', 'secret', datetime(2013, 3, 3)),
...              Contact('5551234', 'abrown@example.com')),
...     Employee(1, Person('Bob', 'Jones'),
...              Account('bjones', 'safe', datetime(2013, 3, 3)),
...              Contact('5555678', 'bjones@example.com')),
...     Employee(2, Person('Carol', 'Smith'),
...              Account('csmith', 'hidden', datetime(2013, 3, 3)),
...              Contact('5559012', 'csmith@example.com'))]
```

and a template (you could read this from a file as easily)

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> template = StringIO.StringIO('''employee.id
... employee.manager.first_name
... employee.user.last_login
... employee.contact.phone_number''')
```

To use the expression compiler, you need an Environment;  no options need be
specified:

```
>>> import jinja2
>>> env = jinja2.Environment()
>>> template_filter = map(env.compile_expression, template)
```

As I mentioned, use the csv module:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import sys
>>> writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
```

finally, with the compiled expressions, we can run over the data, one 'row' at
a time, and for each row, apply each expression

```
>>> writer.writerows([[field(employee=row) for field in template_filter]
...                   for row in data])
0,Alice,2013-03-03 00:00:00,5551234
1,Bob,2013-03-03 00:00:00,5555678
2,Carol,2013-03-03 00:00:00,5559012
```

Comment: Thanks TokenMacGuy, that's exactly what I want to do, but the list of items I'm outputing (as well as the order) is unknown at programming time - that is, the items you have in the yield section are defined by the user at runtime. What I'm looking for is a way to do exactly what you show here, but with the items that go into the yield section defined by the end user (eg. by specifying them in a text file).

Answer (score 0):

The Django Docs are an excellent resource - http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

All you need to know is the dot notation used in python to access object properties.

Comment: One bad thing, however, is that they forget to use `.writerows` and just use `.wrtiterow`